# Setting Quad9 as DNS via Power Shell Script (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, powershell, dns

Due to Corona, I am facing the task to explain many people how to change their DNS resolver to [Quad9](https://www.quad9.net/) - and unfortunately, many users feel overwhelmed by the official manual. So the question came up to provide a shell script that does the work.

Ever seen such a script? Any idea if that could work at all? Any idea where to start? Thanks for sharing your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like

```bsh
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex 12 –ServerAddresses (“10.0.0.1”,”10.0.0.2”)
```